# json returned from flickr api not getting parsed

Tags: json, node.js, flickr

I am trying to consume flickr api and requesting data in json format from a node.js server. I am providing `nojsoncallback=1` so that returned json is not wrapped inside a jsonp callback. Here is the url http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1.

Json returned is not properly formatted and `JSON.parse` is unable to parse it. If I don't pass `nojsoncallback` query param and `eval` the response which calls `jsonFlickrFeed` function, it gets `eval`ed properly and I get the object. I also notice that the `Content-type` header in the response is `application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8`. I suspect that the special characters are double escaped in returned response.

I don't want to `eval`, what can I do to convert the response correctly into a string and then parse it?

By the way here is the [**`gist`**](https://gist.github.com/juzerali/7934789) with simplest use case. No modules, no middlewares.

Comment: I would imagine that the `nojsoncallback` flag on the API is designed for use with server-to-server communications, not from an end client using javascript which will likely fail due to being a cross-domain call.  Just use the jsonp.

Comment: I should've mentioned it, I am calling the api from node.js server. I have mentioned it now and also added a tag node.js.

Comment: @JuzerAli Could you provide us with the code you use in Node? Depending on how you do it, the response from Flickr should be usable *as-is* (Since the response is JSON with `application/x-javascript;` as `Content-Type`).

Comment: It was a mess back then, here is the [link](https://github.com/juzerali/photoawe/commit/d7997cb103d42e9db5cd15d41b281344e5b30265#diff-0364f57fbff2fabbe941ed20c328ef1aR50). I am using the `rest` node module. I tried another module for calling rest endpoints as well with the same result.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/juzerali/7934789) is the simplest use case. No node modules, no middlewares, simple http request. Please upvote the question to help it gain traction.

Comment: The JSON is definitely invalid. Apparently, the JSON serializer escapes single quotes `'`, e.g., source: "It's an error" becomes "It\'s an error". Please file a bug report.

Comment: [Filed a bug](http://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/yws-flickr/conversations/topics/8465)

Comment: @JuzerAli You helped me solve this problem on my flickr web app. I was getting a headache trying to figure why my response object was coming out wonky.